# :nth-child not working on anchor tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a page template with a header, side bar, footer and content section. Everything is fixed  except the content section scrolls on overflow.

The header contains a basic navigation bar comprising of an unordered list, four list items and four anchor tags which link to the normal 'home' 'content''about' 'contact' pages.

Each link needs a right border, except the last (4th) one. They are solely to visually separate each one.

Here's the code:

```css
#top-nav {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top-nav ul {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  height:68px; /*100%, border     doesn't span full height*/
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 23.5px 95px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#top-nav li:nth-child(4) {
  border-right: none;
}

#top-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--  <PAGE HEADER>  -->
<div id="header">
  <header>

    <!--  <HEADER TITLE>  -->
    <div id="header-title">
      <h1>Page Header</h1>
    </div>
    <!--  </HEADER TITLE>  -->

    <!--  <HEADER NAVBAR>  -->
    <div id="top-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Content</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--  </HEADER NAVBAR  -->

  </header>
</div>
<!--  </HEADER>   -->
```

This code works as expected.

What I want to do is move the styling aspects to the anchor tag.

When I transfer the styles to the anchor tag and change the `nth-child` to a instead of li, it doesn't work.

I have also tried `:last-child`, but it has the same outcome, works on li but not on a.

**EDIT:**

Here's the CSS:

```
#top-nav {
    background-color:orange;
    height:68px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 

#top-nav ul {
    font-size:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 

#top-nav li {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    height:68px; /*100%, border     doesn't span full height*/
    margin:0;
/*  border-right:1px solid black;*/
/*  padding:23.5px 95px;*/
display:inline-block;
} 

#top-nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    padding:23.5px 95px;
    font-size:16px;
    display:block;


#top-nav a:nth-child(4) {
    border-right:none;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I mean... How many children do the `li` elements have? In what position is the `a`? Because from what I see, all the `a` elements are `:nth-child(1)`...

Comment: You want to design the `a`'s inside `li` right?

Comment: Just an hint: better to post the code that doesn't work, not the one that works..

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If I set a right border for the li elements, and then use #top-nav li:nth-child(4) {border-right:none;} it removes the border from the fourth list item. I assumed the fourth li would be the fourth child of the ul, but I guess it doesn't work that way?

Comment: @Tesseract Yes that's correct. I want the li's to contain the anchors, but that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that'll be enough to add the `a` selector to the rule that already works for you:

```
#top-nav li:nth-child(4) a{
  border-right: none;
}
```

The `nth-child` selector works for siblings tags, so it's correct to use it on the `li` tags. Adding the `a` selector, you're saying that you want to style the `a` tag contained in the 4th `li`.

CSS style is applied to the last selector. The previous ones work as context (or containers).

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Can you please explain why this method works?

Comment: Added brief explanation in the answer.

Comment: That makes sense, but why does it work normal on the li but the a has to be accessed through li?

Comment: It can't work directly on the `a` because the `a` tags aren't siblings: "Sibling elements must have the same parent element, and _adjacent_ means _immediately following_" ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)).